# WordPress Content Directory Setting

Tags: wordpress, settings

I have installed CiviCRM successfully for WordPress. However, the Civi dashboard shows many 404 errors. My install directory is `content/plugins/civicrm` and the dashboard is searching for `wp-content/plugins/civicrm`. I am not able to find a setting that tells Civi where to look for the content directory. Is this something that I can modify?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to say that you'll have to revert back to the default 'wp-content' folder name in order to use CiviCRM. I can find at least 5 places in CiviCRM core where this is hard-coded.

Comment: I agree with Christian.   I have been looking at this again recently as this is a blocker to many things.   Christian, thoughts on trying to work together to remove these hard coded references? The problem I see is when CiviCRM runs a process that does not bootstrap wp.   This had been the issue with the PayPal IPN, I am certain a few others are still out there.

Comment: Whilst the `wpLoadPhp` setting is a good start (and was sufficient to get Paypal IPN working) Civi-for-WP needs to be more sensitive to its context. There are a stack of other possible constants that WordPress uses to define its environment - as Corey's question demonstrates. And that's without raising the issue of Multisite. Kevin, I'd happily work on this with you during Edale, even if you're only present remotely ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have WP installed in a subdirectory with the content directory in the doc root. My solution has been to create a sym link named `wp-content` inside the WP subdirectory that points to my content directory. This is working for me (so far) without issue.

Comment: That's a neat workaround, thanks for sharing.